# Spring MVC: www.example.com do not recognize the session initiated in example.com

Tags: spring, session, spring-mvc, spring-security

I access my website as `example.com` and login  now i am logged in.
now if i access my website as `www.example.com` it show the same content ,same page evrthing same except it don't recognize the previous login session and so it show the content as a Guest user not a logged in user.

Why adding `www.example.com` do not recognize the session initiated in `example.com` ?

Answer (score 1):

Have a read of this page to get a understanding on why use www and not [http://www.yes-
www.org/why-use-www/](http://www.yes-www.org/why-use-www/). Go about half way and it will explain all cookie fun.

Using www stored cookies differently then not using it, one focuses on sharing the cookie across whole domain, where as other method only allows the cookie within the immediate subdomain.

Hope that helps clarify.